# inotifywait ignoring new folders in watch directory

Tags: shell-script, inotify

I am trying to use inotifywait to watch a folder (/shares/Photos) and when it detects a jpg added to the folder I need to resize it into a sub directory ($small_dir). Under the photos director there will be many subfolders for the jpgs.

The tree looks like this

```
shares
  -Photos
      -Folder 1
      -Folder 2
       .
       .
       .
```

Basically whenever someone copies pictures into `folder 1` I need to create a new subfolder, and then resize the images and put the smaller versions into that folder.

So the tree would become:

```
shares
  -Photos
      -Folder 1
          -Resized
      -Folder 2
       .
       .
       .
```

My code so far:

```
inotifywait -mr --timefmt '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' --format '%T %w %f' -e close_write /shares/Photos --includei "\.jpg|\.jpeg" |
while read -r date time dir file; do
    changed_abs=${dir}${file}
    small_dir=${dir}${target}/
    
    printf "\nFile $changed_abs was changed or created\n  dir=$dir \n  file=$file \n  small_dir=$small_dir \n"
    
    # Check if the $small_directory exists, if not create it.
    if [ -d "$small_dir" -a ! -h "$small_dir" ]
    then
        echo "$small_dir found, nothing to do."
    else
        echo "Creating $small_dir"
        mkdir $small_dir
        chmod 777 $small_dir
    fi
    
    # Check to see if the file is in $small_dir, if it is, do nothing.  
    if [ "$dir" = "$small_dir" ]; then
        printf "\nFile is in the $small_dir folder, nothing to do\n"
    else
        printf "\nResizing file into the $small_dir folder\n"
        # Code to resize the image goes here.
    fi
        
done
```

It mostly works, but what I am banging my head against the wall about is that if I create a new subfolder under `Photos` while the script is running, inotifywait simply ignores it and does nothing.

I tried replacing `close_write` with `create` but it made no difference, and I am really not sure where to go from here.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just realized that my method to check if the files are not in the $small_dir does not work, this only seemed to work due to `inotifywait` ignoring all new sub directories. I'll rework this after I fix the new director issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP is using:

> ```
> inotifywait -mr --timefmt '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' --format '%T %w %f' -e close_write /shares/Photos --includei "\.jpg|\.jpeg" |
> ```

The documentation about [`--includei`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/inotify-tools/inotifywait.1#includei) tells (bold emphasis mine):

> `--includei <pattern>`
>
> **Process events** only for the subset of files whose filenames match the specified POSIX regular expression, case insensitive.

That's not: "display events" but "process events". Indeed that means that only events about directories with a name including `.jpg` or `.jpeg` will be processed.

A directory creation event occuring but not matching the filter won't be processed, so `inotifywait` will not call [`inotify_add_watch(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/inotify_add_watch.2) on this event and later anything happening in this . As a result, there will never be events watched in this subdirectory.

I couldn't find with `--includei` or other similar options a way to express "process events only for these regex, *or also* with any directory".

---

**UPDATE**: suggest a workaround

So the way to get it working appears to have to filter outside of the command. GNU `grep` will buffer its output if not a tty, so add `--line-buffered`.

This will be affected by user input (like spaces in filenames). To mitigate this, using a `/` separator (which is invalid in a filename) between the directory and filename is needed. As the directory part conveniently includes a trailing `/`, just removing the space in the format string is enough (along further variable processing and reuse like `changed_abs`). At the same time, I'm correcting the intent to filter filenames *ending* with the strings `jpg` or `jpeg`, not *including* these strings, and probably improving initial handling of directories with space inside (affectations of `changed_abs` and `small_dir` but there are more later to fix). OP should really protect all relevant variables with quotes in the script (`{ }` doesn't replace quotes).

Replace:

> ```bsh
> inotifywait -mr --timefmt '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' --format '%T %w %f' -e close_write /shares/Photos --includei "\.jpg|\.jpeg" |
> while read -r date time dir file; do
>     changed_abs=${dir}${file}
>     small_dir=${dir}${target}/
> ```

with:

```bsh
inotifywait -mr --timefmt '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' --format '%T %w%f' -e close_write /shares/Photos |
    grep --line-buffered -Ei '/[^/]*\.(jpg|jpeg)$' |
while read -r date time changed_abs; do
    [ -d "$changed_abs" ] && continue # a directory looking like a picture filename was written to: skip this event
    dir="${changed_abs%/*}/"
    file="${changed_abs##*/}"
    small_dir="${dir}${target}/"
```

Not completely tested, but that's the idea. I'm not even sure the directory test is needed (it appears there is never a `close_write` event on it), but it won't hurt.

---

Notes

- if this isn't clear, an action (`inotify_add_watch(2)`) has to be done by `inotifywait` for each directory creation event detected, `inotifywait` must *as soon as possible* add a new watch to this directory because it might lose following events inside it (race condition). It's even documented in the [BUGS](https://manpages.debian.org/inotify-tools/inotifywait.1#BUGS) section:

  > There are race conditions in the recursive directory watching code [...] probably not
  > fixable.
- newer versions of `inotifywait`, when running as root (or privileged enough) on kernel >= 5.9 at least, are supposed to be able to use the [`fanotify(7)`](https://manpages.debian.org/fanotify.7) facility, but I couldn't manage to get my version of `inotifywait` to use this despite being supposed to be compiled with support and having a recent enough kernel. On a system where `fanotify(7)` would be used, combined with the `--filesystem` option, hypothetically this could remove the need to have to do an action for each newer directory and make OP's method based on filtering with `--includei` work.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense and I just tested it with a new folder called new.jpg and sure enough changes where detected and processed.

So how do you suggest I do this with `inotifywait` ?

Comment: Thanks!! Only problem is it now ignores everything... lol.

I think I do see what you are getting to there, reading in the entire path and file name, then tearing that into director and filename. I am not sure I understand the note about working around the space in the folder/filename.

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted you suggestion verbatim for testing.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Unrelated question, if I wanted `inotifywait` to complete ignore all instances of the `resized` folder (this is the folder that the resized images are going to be in), would it be best to do that via the --excluded option, and if so, what would that look like?

Comment: v2: `--exclude '/resized(/.*)?$'` looks promising.

Comment: Thank you!!! That did it. I really need to dedicate sometime to learning regex.